# Name of Current App in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using the Google App Engine Python API is there a way to access the name of the currently running application--i.e., the app name specified in your `app.yaml` file with `application: foobar`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
import os
appname = os.environ['APPLICATION_ID']
```

EDIT: I just noticed this because I got a new upvote on it today (shame on you, upvoter!), but this is no longer correct.

```
from google.appengine.api.app_identity import get_application_id
appname = get_application_id()
```

should be used. The value in `os.environ` will include a "s~" prefix for applications using the HR datastore and, by default, "dev~" on the development server. (`os.environ` should also be avoided entirely on App Engine anyway, since when concurrency support is added with the Python 2.7 runtime, use of `os.environ` won't be threadsafe and will allow data to leak from one request to another, although obviously the application ID itself would be the same for multiple requests to the same application at the same time...)

Comment: Nice. Thanks! Is this in the docs anywhere? I couldn't for the life of me find it.

Comment: Thanks for revisiting and fixing!

Comment: It's `from google.appengine.api.app_identity import get_application_id` BTW. =)

Comment: Current docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/